# What happens when an ARP Request arrives to an Ethernet switch?

Tags: ethernet, arp, broadcast

I remember reading somewhere that switches defined "data link layer broadcast domains": that is, data link broadcasts from one network connected to the switch are not forwarded to the others.

If this is true, what happens when a host directly connected to a switch makes an ARP request? Does it go beyond the switch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of a basic switch—that is, without getting into VLANs and so-called "layer-3 switches"—the switch is NOT the edge of a broadcast domain. ARP broadcasts, like all broadcasts, are sent to all ports of the switch (except the one they came in on).

You may have heard that switches separate *collision* domains, which is true, but is a separate concept from broadcast domains.